# Confused about the proof of a lemma about deleted products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes

I am confused about the proof of Lemma 2.1 in the paper [**Obstructions to the imbedding of a complex in a euclidean space. I: The first obstruction**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969998), by A. Shapiro, Ann. Math. 66 (1957).

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex, whose geometric realization is $|K|$. To use the same notation as in the paper, let $|K|^*$ be the topological space $|K|\times |K| \setminus |K|$. On the other hand, let $K^*$ denote "the subcomplex of the cell complex, $K \times K$, consisting of products of pairs of simplices having no vertex in common". Let $|K^*|$ be the geometric realization of $K^*$. We have an inclusion of spaces $|K^*|\hookrightarrow |K|^*$, and Lemma 2.1 says that this inclusion is a ($\Sigma_2$-equivariant) homotopy equivalence. Here are the lemma and its proof as they appear in the paper (do not worry about $\bar K$):

[image]

My problem is with the definition of the map $\beta$. I don't see how it can be continuous in cases when $p$ and $q$ have some coordinates in common.

For example, suppose $K$ is a $2$-simplex. So $|K|=\{(x, y, z)\mid x, y, z\ge 0, x+y+z=1\}$. Suppose $p=\left(\frac{5}{12}, \frac{1}{3} + \epsilon, \frac{1}{4} -\epsilon\right)$, where $0\le \epsilon < \frac{1}{12}$, and $q=\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{5}{12}\right)$. According to my understanding, when $\epsilon>0$, $\beta(p, q)=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}+\epsilon}\left(\frac{5}{12}, \frac{1}{3} + \epsilon,0\right)$, whereas when $\epsilon =0$, $\beta(p, q)=(1, 0, 0)$, so it is not continuous.

I believe that the lemma is correct, and I think I know how to fix the proof. But I would like to know if this really is a mistake or I am confusing myself unnecessarily. If this proof is incomplete, I would be interested in knowing about other, quotable, proofs of the result in the literature.

Comment: Your analysis seems correct to me.  However, I think that if we define $\delta(p,q)_v=\max(p_v-q_v,0)$ and $\rho(r)_v=r_v/\sum_wr_w$ and $f(p,q)=(\rho(\delta(p,q)),\rho(\delta(q,p)))$ then we get a correct deformation retraction of $|K|^2\setminus\Delta$ onto $|K^*|$.

Comment: This was my fix as well. I just felt I needed a sanity check. Thanks!